# T-SQL Table and other variables in one DECLARE block

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, syntax

The following fails to compile:

```
  DECLARE
    @DateFrom Date = '20151225',
    @DateTo Date = '20151226',
    @Ids TABLE (Id Int NOT NULL);
```

with the error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.

But when I add its own `DECLARE` for the table variable declaration, it compiles perfectly:

```
 DECLARE
    @DateFrom Date = '20151225',
    @DateTo Date = '20151226';

 DECLARE
    @Ids TABLE (Id Int NOT NULL);
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78b9a) is the SQL fiddle.

What is wrong with the first snippet? We aren't allowed to declare a table variables sharing the same `DECLARE` block with other variable declarations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [`DECLARE` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx):

> When declaring table variables, the table variable must be the only variable being declared in the DECLARE statement.

You can see it clearly in the syntax too:

```
DECLARE 
{ 
    { @local_variable [AS] data_type  | [ = value ] }
  | { @cursor_variable_name CURSOR }
} [,...n] 
| { @table_variable_name [AS] <table_type_definition> }
```

One or more `@local_variable`s can be declared (the `[,...n]` part), or only one `@table_variable_name`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know what makes SQL Server require only one table variable declaration per a `DECLARE` block? Is it related to a T-SQL syntax limitation? Or maybe to the way SQL Server compiles/executes/whatever that declarations?

Answer (score 3):

In case if you want first snippet to work, Create [***table types***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx).

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ids as TABLE(Id Int NOT NULL)

DECLARE
    @DateFrom Date = '20151225',
    @DateTo Date = '20151226',
    @Ids dbo.ids;
```

**Note:** If you use `Table type` as *input parameter* to `FUNCTION/STORED PROCEDURE` you need to declare it as `READONLY`